# How can i edit a template?

Tags: titles, templates, overleaf

I found this template https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/wiley-journal-template/nnjcnfyhzcqp
and I want to hide the Correspondence, Present address and Funding information. For example when I delete the `\fundinginfo` command it only removes the text, but not the Funding information title.

Comment: Welcome to TeX stackexchange. Please edit your post to include a minimal working example showing what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the class file that's in the template. Namely,use `\ifdefempty` to check whether the Funding information is empty.

Take these lines (477-479 in `wiley-article.cls`):

```
  \vskip10pt%
  \textbf{Funding information}\\
  \@fundinginfo\par
```

and change them to this:

```
  \ifx\empty\@fundinginfo
  \else
    \vskip10pt
    \textbf{Funding information}\\
    \@fundinginfo\par
  \fi
```

Then if you invoke `\fundinginfo{}` in the preamble, things should work properly. You can do similar modifications to the other fields.